# Can't update WordFence Options, clear data manually

Tags: database, mysql, phpmyadmin

I ran across this problem today. Found enough bits on Stack Overflow to finally get me there, but figured I'd post a coherent answer to my question.

Problem: I can't save changes in WordFence, and need it to clear it's data on uninstall so I can reinstall it cleanly.

I found the data in the database table wp_wfConfig, but all settings are saved as `blob` or `longblob`.

How can I change the settings so the data all clears on deleting the plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a post on Stack Overflow advising that converting a column from `blob` to `text` should result in no data loss. I didn't really care about data loss since I wanted to remove the plugin data anyway, so I gave it a shot.

On the Structure tab in phpMyAdmin, I edited the val column and changed it to text. Then I found the option for deleteTablesOnDeact and changed the value from 0 to 1.

After doing this, I was able to deactivate the plugin and the tables were all removed.